# Integration of $e^{x^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone help me solve following indefinite integral? I've been trying to work this out for quite some time now. Not a math major myself and the last time I did any undergrad college level calculus was back in 2013. Hence it might seem easy for a lot of you but please do help. I'm trying to brush up my calculus again.
The question is

> Solve
> $$f(x) = \int e^{x^n}\, dx $$

Comment: Thank you for including context. But tell us, what have you tried, where are you stuck? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) should help you.

Comment: For $n = 1$, $\int e^{x} \ dx = e^x$. For $n=2$, $\int e^{x^2} \ dx$ is not an elementary function. Perhaps the same is true for $n > 2$, I don't know.

Comment: Well i tried substituting y = $x^n$ but things go down hill after that since then I've to use by-parts to integrate the exponential and the algebraic components. I must admit my current level of skill at integrations, esp the clever ones, is at best pre college level. I only remember all the formulae but don't remember how to mould the integrals to apply them easily

Comment: For "brushing up" calculus, choose integrals from textbooks, where they are chosen to have solutions using elementary methods.  Most integrals have no elementary answers.

Answer (score 2):

With $t=-x^n$ and odd $n$, the integral becomes

$$\int e^{x^n}dx=-\frac1n\int t^{1/n-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$

This is an incomplete Gamma integral, though it is usually not used with negative bounds.

Comment: Ahh YESSSS thanks a lot. That explains it. Had completely forgotten about gamma int! Didn't even consider it until you pointed it out.

Comment: @ChandramouliChaudhuri: in a way, this is a negative answer. It proves that there is no closed-form solution.